# C# Sending data via Serial Port, data in byte array is received incomplete

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, buffer, data-loss

I am developing a GUI interface which receives information from an ATmega8A.
The below code from the GUI has to do the following:

- Check Header: Here, I am reading data into a Byte Array (`byte[] test`) which is getting checked against `OxFF`
- If `header == 0xFF`, read the second byte array (`byte[] data`)

Please see the code below.

Now, I have the following problem. If I send simply a number, for example 1, that number is getting displayed in the `textBox1` without any problems. However, if I am trying to send a number like  433, I am always receiving 4, 33 is getting lost. I assume it is due to my included if-statement, but I cannot explain why that data is being lost.

```
namespace RS232
{
   public partial class fclsRS232Tester : Form
   {
    string InputData = String.Empty;
    string initText = "waiting...";

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    public fclsRS232Tester()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Nice methods to browse all available ports:
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        // Add all port names to the combo box:
        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            cmbComSelect.Items.Add(port);
        }

        cmbBaud.Items.Add(2400);
        cmbBaud.Items.Add(9600);

        cmbComSelect.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cmbBaud.SelectedIndex = 1;

        button4.Enabled = false;
        textBox1.Text = initText;
        textBox2.Text = initText;

    }

    private void cmbComSelect_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (port.IsOpen) port.Close();
        port.PortName = cmbComSelect.SelectedItem.ToString();
        stsStatus.Text = port.PortName + ": 9600,8N1";

        // try to open the selected port:
        try
        {
            port.Open();
            button4.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
        }
        // give a message, if the port is not available:
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Serial port " + port.PortName + " cannot be opened!", "RS232      tester", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            cmbComSelect.SelectedText = "";
            stsStatus.Text = "Select serial port!";
        }
    }

    private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int bytenumber;
        int bufferSize = port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] test = new byte[1];
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
        byte[] data2 = new byte[bufferSize];

        port.Read(test, 0, 1);

        if (test[0] == 0xFF)  //Receive X-andY- coordinates from MCU and plot the coordinates 
        {
            bytenumber = port.Read(data, 0, bufferSize);
            string info = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.txtIn.Text += info;                      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of object does `port` contain?

Comment: I defined port in the following way:

Comment: InitializeComponent();

            // Nice methods to browse all available ports:
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            // Add all port names to the combo box:
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                cmbComSelect.Items.Add(port);
            }

Comment: That can't be the `port` that is used in the method. That variable exist only in the scope of the `foreach`, and a string doesn't have any `BytesToRead` property or `Read` method.

Comment: I also included the following code:  private void cmbComSelect_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (port.IsOpen) port.Close();
            port.PortName = cmbComSelect.SelectedItem.ToString();
            stsStatus.Text = port.PortName + ": 9600,8N1";

            // try to open the selected port:
            try
            {
                port.Open();
                button4.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
            }

Comment: That's more code that just uses `port`. Where is it declared?

Comment: It seems I don't have a declaration beside the above code. Can this be true?

Comment: It has to be declared somewhere, but it might not be in the code that you are looking at. Do you have a control in the page with that name?

Comment: I just included my complete code above. I am new in C# so I am doing still lot of readings.

Comment: change your first read to `var firstRead = port.Read(data, 0, buffersize);` and after that add `Debug.WriteLine(firstRead);` and `Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));` check in the Debug Output window of Visual Studio if you receive the data you expect.

Comment: This is entirely by design, you only get as many bytes as are available in the receive buffer.  Usually not more than one or two.  You have to change your code so you don't start processing the data until you've received *all* of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem got solved by storing all data into a buffer:

private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytenumber;
            byte[] data = new byte[10];

```
        bytenumber = port.Read(data, 0, 10);

        if (data[0] == 0xFF)
        {
        }
    }
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The DataReceived handler is called whenever data is available in the received buffer. So read all data in the buffer and then process for validity of header and so forth before the next burst of data is received. Once new data is received the old data is over-written leading to data loss.
In your case you are reading only 1 byte with your call to port.Read(). I would change that to **port.Read(test, 0, bufferSize);**

Further, I would just store the data in a buffer and have the data processing run on a separate thread. The more time you spend time in the handler, greater are the chances of losing data.